# Mono - Compiler as Service, how to create instance of the compiled class

Tags: compiler-construction, mono

I am using this simple program :-

```
var evaluator = new Evaluator(
  new CompilerSettings(),
  new Report(new ConsoleReportPrinter()));

// Make it reference our own assembly so it can use IFoo
evaluator.ReferenceAssembly(typeof(IFoo).Assembly);

// Feed it some code
evaluator.Compile(
            @"
public class Foo : MonoCompilerDemo.IFoo
{
    public string Bar(string s) { return s.ToUpper(); }
}");
```

Is there a way , I can use the instance of compiled class foo with in the main program. There is overload in compile that takes a delegate, but I am unable to understand its usage

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar solution and had no luck finding anything. Until I did something like this...

```cs
Assembly asm = ((Type)evaluator.Evaluate("typeof(Foo);")).Assembly;
dynamic script = asm.CreateInstance("Foo");
script.Bar("hello")
```

Given this snippet with the simple program. `script.Bar("hello")` would produce "HELLO"

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add this fragment to the code you are executing to compile your class?

```
// define class Foo like you already did
return typeof(Foo);
```

and then

```
var type = (Type)evaluator.Compile(...
var myFooInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

or even better, just compile a "factory method" into your code :)

```
// define class Foo like you already did
return new Func<IFoo>(() => new Foo());
```

and then "outside" you just cast the returned value back into a `Func<IFoo>` and use it:

```
var fooFactory = (Func<IFoo>)evaluator.Compile(...
var instance = fooFactory();
```